# MySQL SELECT is very slow because LONGBLOB

Tags: mysql, performance

why or how solve problem on mysql.

```
table xxx
-> id primary key
-> name varchar 255
-> data longblob
```

when I store to this table 100 files, each 100MB, the table would have 10GB

and then try to select any row... it takes to long

```
SELECT name FROM xxx WHERE id = 50 LIMIT 1;
```

takes about 8 second

my problem is probably in that, mysql reads whole row before it return `name`, which is only 255 characters ... so when I want to list names of 100 files, mysql reads 10 GB and return about 2 KB of result.

Comment: StackExchange shows a preview of your question/answer as you write it. Please look at the preview and make sure that the formatting is correct. If the preformatted code you write is displayed as a single line in the preview, that's how it'll look to everyone else. So use the "code sample" button to format it properly (or just put 4 spaces before each line and SE will know it's preformatted code).

Answer (score 7):

Try splitting the blobs into a separate table.

For example, you could have a table `xxx` containing the columns `id` and `name`, and another table `xxx_data` containing the columns `id` and `data`.  If you only want the name, you don't need to query the `xxx_data` table at all; if you need both the name and the data, you can join the tables together using the shared primary key `id`:

```sql
SELECT id, name, data
FROM xxx JOIN xxx_data USING (id)
WHERE id = ...
```

For more information and optimization ideas, see e.g. [10 tips for optimizing MySQL queries](http://20bits.com/articles/10-tips-for-optimizing-mysql-queries-that-dont-suck/).

Comment: I would just add on top of this that you should consider storing these files on the file system instead in the database. Of course there are reasons to store them in the database (like security, easy to delete, easy replicate across many servers etc.) but imagine that you want to return 10 files...you query the database and then store 10 *100MB in the RAM. Do you really want to consume 1GB of RAM on your server just to return the files, while you can just stream them from some location on your server? I think that your files are kind of too large to be stored in the database.

Comment: If you don't absolutely need the data in the database you can also move it to the filesystem.  I think this works better when you're dealing with large amounts of files or large files.